# Twitter Bootstrap: making header NOT fixed, but still retaining old behavior

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

My header works great now, but I want to make it not stuck to the top of the viewport.

However, when I change from `.navbar.navbar-fixed-top` to `.navbar`, I lose a lot of my other header functionality: the logo is no longer aligned with the content on my page (instead, it is all the way to the left). Similarly for my links that were aligned with my page's right side- now the links are all the way to the right. Furthermore, the header is slightly rounded, leaving white spots at the upper right and left.

Any easy way to resolve those issues without addressing each one manually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The smaller footprint would be to add

```css
.navbar-fixed-top { position: absolute!important; }
```

Which would replace `fixed` by `absolute`.